# Microsoft Certificate Store

Tags: windows-7, certificate, cryptography

I know that Microsoft Certificate store contains certificates with their corresponding private key. Now when using Microsoft certificate store, do we have to create it ? If yes then how ? or we get it by default with windows, then where it is located in windows 7 ? If possible, please give an example of using MS certificate Store to display all its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a certificate store. There's at least one for your system as a whole, and one for each user. Run `certmgr.msc` to view/manage them.

`certmgr.msc` is an `mmc` (Microsoft Management Console) snap-in. If you're already familiar with mmc, you can add certmgr.msc as one of your standard snap-ins.

Comment: @magicandre1981 The site (or mobile app) apparently turned an edit into a duplicate post. I've deleted the out of date copy.

Comment: @spiff Thanks for this, makes the things very clear. One more thing , Is there method to see the hierarchy of system store and physical stores ?